# Mysql not working properly in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, mysql

when I press mysql in terminal this pops up,

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Something weird stuff happened during setting password when I used these commands

```
apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-server
```

it gave me errors on unmet dependencies.

I used all these command as well

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.6
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I also got this error, please help

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If that fails run:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql*
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```